# What settings are there for sending an email to the users who create accounts?

Tags: users

How can I send an email to users after registration, confirming they have been registered?

From user/register, when users enter the required data (name, username, email) as administrator I receive the account information, but the users don't get any message.

Answer (score 0):

In **configuration > people > account settings** or going to `config/people/accounts` you can set who gets what and even modify the text

### Register without admin approval

Check this setting

```
Who can register accounts? : visitors
```

and the user that registers will receive `Welcome (no approval required)` email which will include a one time link to complete registration.  Upon clicking on the link and following the instructions he is a registered user.

### Register with admin approval

check the following setting

```
Who can register accounts? : Visitors, but administrator approval is required
```

The user will get `Admin (user awaiting approval)` email upon registering and if enabled on `Account activation` the setting `Notify user when account is activated` is enabled the user will get a 2nd email upon admin approval.

[image]

Comment: Thank you and I am sorry for the late reply, I just got back. I have set up "Visitors, but administrator approval is required". Is there a way to send out the email with admin approval on?

Comment: modified the answer please check

Comment: A million thanks. I'll do as you say and let you know.

Comment: Hello, I checked and all these settings are enabled. Still the user gets no email. Any guesses what might be wrong? Thank you again.

Comment: Are you sure your system can actually send emails ? does password reminder send email ?

Comment: Hello again, it finally works now but emails end up in the spam folder. Do you think this is related to https? I bought an ssl certificate but it works only  if you type the site name with https not with http. I haven't been able to redirect all traffic to https from the htacess file. Can that be the problem? Thank you again for your help. I am from Thessaloniki.

Comment: @kyriakib nice to see you here. What you are asking is not related to https and its a whole different subject and not specific to drupal.  I think you should start with searching some articles on "prevent emails from going to spam" and there is probably some drupal modules to help with that but its a coordination between setting things in drupal and on your DNS settings.

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. Something unexpected came up. Thank you  for letting me know. I asked the hosting provider and they changed some settings. It will be all right soon. Thanks again.